# computed hashybtes column used as primary key

Tags: t-sql, md5, calculated-columns

I have long gene sequence which could be the natural primary key, but I'm looking for a way to find a more succinct alternative representation of the natural key. Do not want to use a surrogate key. Not worried about performance, since there will not be a lot of joins to worry about where the efficiency of the PK is an issue.

Is this possible?

```
        create table foo(
           myvalue varchar(2000) not null,
           md5 as hashbytes('MD5',myvalue) PERSISTED   PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL   -- bad syntax
         )
```

If so, what's the correct syntax? The above is not correct.

Also can I create a child table and set up an FK relationship?  I do not find the Limitations section in the documentation clear about this:

```
          create table fooChild(
          id int primary key not null,
          md5 varbinary(16)
           )

         alter table fooChild add constraint FK_FOOCHILD_FOO
         foreign key(md5) references FOO(md5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer. http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15397

Basically you have to ensure a function cannot return null so wrap hashbytes in isnull or coalesce.

Comment: SQL Server permits me to create the PK in that manner. But creating the FK is a problem -- `Column 'FOO.md5' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'fooChild.md5' in foreign key 'FK_FOOCHILD_FOO'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.`  It looks as though the PK is varbinary(8000).

Comment: This is straight out of MSDN I hope it helps. Allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes. The output conforms to the algorithm standard: 128 bits (16 bytes) for MD2, MD4, and MD5; 160 bits (20 bytes) for SHA and SHA1; 256 bits (32 bytes) for SHA2_256, and 512 bits (64 bytes) for SHA2_512.

Comment: Just a had an idea you might try for the wrapping your primary key formula with CONVERT(VARBINARY(16),[formula here]) then your FK might work.